# Multiple Scripts/Spiders writing to different CSV files. Will this code cause any problems?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm building some spiders to do some web scraping and am trying to figure out if my code is ok as written before I start building them out. The spiders will run via crontab at the same time, though they each write to a separate file.

```py
with open(item['store_name']+'price_list2.csv', mode='a', newline ='') as price_list2:       
    savepriceurl2 = csv.writer(price_list2, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    savepriceurl2.writerow([item['url']]+item['price'])
```

I'm not sure how the 'open as price_list2' or 'savepriceurl2 = csv.writer' parts of the code work, and will the spiders get mixed up if they all use the same names, even for a different csv file, if they are all running at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the minimal code posted it is difficult to say if there will be an issue with two. Assuming that the code you posted will run in each instance of the object (I assume) they will be writing to whatever store they are scraping (defined by your `item['store_name']`.

Regarding your questions about the code, the `open(...) as price_list2` returns an `io.TextIOWrapper` object (details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)) which is stored as the variable price_list. You could achieve the same by writing: `price_list2 = open(...)`however then you must close the file in order to not leak memory/data. However by writing it as `with open(...) as file:` means you do not have to call `file.close()` and thus ensures the file is always closed after usage.

The other line you asked about, `savepriceurl2 = csv.writer(...)` creates an object that simplifies writing to the actual file. Thus, you can simply use the object function `writerow()` to easily write a row to the desired file. More information on that can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

So basically what your code is doing is this:

1. Open an object that represents a file. In your case you have also specified that you will append to the file if it exists (due to the type being 'a')
2. Create a csv writer instance that will write to the file object `price_list2` with the delimiter `','` (and some other options, check the link for details)
3. Tell the csv writer to write a row to the file which is the concatenation of the value of `item['url']` and `item['price']`

For your last question, given there is no information on your actual design and setup, I am assuming that each spider is an instance of the class that holds this file. As long as each spider is going to different sites (thus meaning that one spider will not have `item['store_name']` be the same as the other spider, you should be writing to different files. As long as this is the case it should be fine (I'm not aware of issues of writing two to files 'at the same time' in python). If this is not the case you will run into issues if your spiders try to write to the same file at the same time.

As a tip, googling the functions will often get you the description and clarification on functions quicker than a post here and will have a lot more information.

I hope this helps and clarifies things for you.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. You are correct, each spider will use that same piece of code, but on different websites/store names. I thought I had seen a thread on here talking about an issue with different spiders getting their outputs mixed up but I can't find it anymore. I appreciate the explanation on the object / write instance. I looked at the python page for csv reading/writing but couldn't make much sense of it. Thanks again!